# LibGDX Shader does not work with FBO texture

Tags: libgdx, shaders, frame-buffer

I have a shader and I want to run the shader on the whole rendered image at the end instead of each individual sprite that I render on screen. For this purpose I created an FBO, I render the all my images to the FBO and then I render to colorBufferTexture generated by the FBO. There is just one problem, the shader does not work when I render the FBO texture. The withoutFbo() method render the image with the shader working just fine, but the withFbo() method only renders the image without the shader. Also I know that the shader in withFbo() is working because if I try to render something other then the colorBufferTexture from the FBO the shader will work. So why isn't the shader working with the texture generated by the FBO?

```
public class Application3 extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    float time;
    Sprite sprite;
    FrameBuffer fbo;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture noiseTexture;
    TextureRegion fboTexture;
    ShaderProgram shaderProgram;

    @Override public void create()
    {
        ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("game.png"));
        sprite.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal(Shader.GLITCH2.getVertex()), Gdx.files.internal(Shader.GLITCH2.getFragment()));

        noiseTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(Shader.GLITCH2.getPath() + "noise.png"));
        noiseTexture.bind(0);

        fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        fboTexture = new TextureRegion(fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
        fboTexture.flip(false, true);
    }

    @Override public void render()
    {
        //withFbo();
        withoutFbo();
    }

    void withoutFbo()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        shaderProgram.setUniformi("u_noise", 0);
        shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_time", time);
        batch.setShader(shaderProgram);
        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());

        batch.setShader(null);
        batch.end();
    }

    void withFbo()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        fbo.begin();
        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());

        batch.end();
        fbo.end();

        shaderProgram.setUniformi("u_noise", 0);
        shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_time", time);
        batch.setShader(shaderProgram);
        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(fboTexture, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());

        batch.setShader(null);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```